# How to get Caret position in pixels in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, caret

How to get Caret position in pixels in `JTextField`? There is a method `getCaret().getDot()`, but it returns symbol count, not pixels. Is there some method besides `FontMetrics`?

Comment: I was about to suggest `FontMetrics` until I read it at the end of your question. I think that is definately the best way. Also, if you look through the java source for JTextComponent, you can probably see how they derive where to paint the caret

Comment: Yes, now I think it's the only way, and not very complicated. @Cruncher you can post an example, I'll vote :)

Comment: Read the comment on my answer. There's limitations to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the API you can use:

```
int pixelPosition = textField.modelToView( textField.getCaretPosition() ).x;
```

Comment: Yes, it is working perfectly, tested. I think this method is even better. Thanks :)

Comment: modelToView is now deprecated - `textField.modelToView2D( textField.getCaretPosition() ).getBounds().x;` should work instead.

Answer (score 2):

Given `JTextField someJTextField` the following code should give you the pixel position of the care:

```
FontMetrics fm = myJTextField.getFontMetrics();
int caret = someJTextField.getCaret().getDot();


int pixelPosition = fm.stringWidth(myJTextField.getText(0, caret)) -
                                   myJTextField.getScrollOffset();
```

Comment: This makes an assumption actually. If you type in more characters than the width of the field, to the point where the leftmost part of the string is no longer visibile, then this won't work.

Comment: I'll think of a more perfect solution tonight

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#getScrollOffset()

Subtracting this from it might do it, but I'll have to do some testing, which I don't have time for right now.

Comment: I tested it - and working! Code looks like: `fm.stringWidth(myJTextField.getText(0, caret)) - myJTextField.getScrollOffset()`. Bingo :)

Comment: Use the `modelToView` method from the `JTextComponent` API.